# Create and manage Powershell-Instances within multiple loops

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, concatenation, begininvoke

At first I created a single Powershell-Instance where I can start my functions. The script for that:

```
$list = [System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()
$row = $list.Rows[1]

$code = {
   param($var)
   $var[0] +"\"+ $var[1]
   #Stuff that has to be done
}

$newPS = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($code).AddArgument($row)
$job = $newPS.BeginInvoke()

while (-not $job.IsCompleted) {}

$result = $newPS.EndInvoke($job)
$newPS.Dispose()

$result
```

So far so good. 
But now I am trying to get to the next level and create that Powershell-Instances for every Element in my Datatable. It should be looking something like this:

```
$list = [System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()

$code = {
    param($var)
    $var[0] +"\"+ $var[1]
    #Stuff that has to be done
    #Start-Sleep -s 1
    }


$PSCount= 1

#start der Funktion
foreach($row in $list)
    {
    $newPS[$PSCount] = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($code).AddArgument($row)
    $job[$PSCount] = $newPS[$PSCount].BeginInvoke()
    $PSCount++
    }



#warten bis alle Jobs kompletiert sind
#Ergebnisse verarbeiten und PS-Instanzen beenden
for($i=1; $i -eq $PSCount; $i++)
    {
    while (-not $job[$i].IsCompleted) {}

    $result = $newPS[$i].EndInvoke($job[$i])
    $newPS[$i].Dispose()
    $result[0]
    }
```

But I cant index a powershell. I also tried to concatenate the powershell-variable instead of making an array:

```
New-Variable -name "newPS$PSCount" -value '[PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($code).AddArgument($row)'
```

But then i dont know how to call the method "beginInvoke()" or variable itself.

Comment: Have you initialised `$newPs` and `$job` as arrays with 2 or more elements? I suggest you start with `$PSCount=0`, and append to the two arrays with `$newPS += ...`

Comment: What is the end goal here? Invoking N powershell instances asynchronously in the same runspace is going to be more memory- and processor-intensive than just doing the work in a loop of N iterations

Comment: @arco444: surprisingly that solved the Problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Matthias R.Jessen: I am going to start Processes on some VM's. So those Processes won't really influence the Powershell-Server.

Answer (score 0):

Just like arco444 said, initialising `$newPS` an `$job` and append those arrays like `$newPS += ...` solved the Problem.